# Configuring Custom PIP point in wso2

Tags: wso2, xacml

Need Help if I am missing any more settings. Description is below

I have written a custom PIP Attribute Finder class by extending

> AbstractPIPAttributeFinder

of wso2's XACML implementation. This PIP point internally calls some services internally for return of values. I am trying to publish in wso2 by doing following configuration but the changes are not reflecting properly in extensions tab of entitlements server.
1. updated `entitlement.propeties` file in `/CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/identity/entitlement.propeties`.
2. Put jar in `/CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib folder`

> Entitlement.properties file settings:

```
PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.1=org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.DefaultAttributeFinder 
PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.2=org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authz.xacml.pip.AuthenticationContextAttributePIP
```

PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.3=oracle.fsgbu.et.dataAccess.CustomPIPAttributeFinder

```
oracle.fsgbu.et.dataAccess.CustomPIPAttributeFinder
```

is my class which resolves the attributes values

Comment: Where is the problem? The class is not found? The attributes are not resolved?

Comment: @gusto2 yes classNotFoundException mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume the entitlement engine is unable to find your class. You have to let the entitlement library know your classes. It can be achieved by OSGi fragments

1. you have to build your package as an OSGi bundle - there are multiple blogs / guides how to do it, e.g. [see this one](https://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin/). You have to use correct dependencies and export your packages
2. drop your bundle jar into the components/dropins, not the libs
3. in the pom.xml specify the fragment-host package, it is the package where your own implementation will be *injected*

**<Fragment-Host>org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement</Fragment-Host>**

That will force your classes to be known by the entitlement engine

part of my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.build.finalName}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.sample.dp.extpip,
                        com.sample.dp.extpip.conf
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip;version="0.0.0",
                        org.osgi.framework,
                        javax.xml.parsers;version="0.0.0",
                        *,
                        !javax.activation
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Fragment-Host>org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement</Fragment-Host>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: It automatically transfers to dropins folder from lib folder

Comment: @RishabhGupta nope... it doesn't transfer. From the `lib` the carbon creates an OSGi bundle with exporting all classes. What is missing is importing your packages into the entitlement bundle (creating a fragment).

Comment: @RishabhGupta once you develop and deploy your bundle, you may use an [osgi console](http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.be/2011/10/debugging-your-osgi-application-using.html) to see if your bundle is properly deployed, started and resolved as a fragment for the entitlement bundle